# Django Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to add some javascript to my Django template from this example, that dynamically changes the backround of rows in a table if a checkbox is selected. http://jsfiddle.net/hkL43/7/

```
$('table').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
$(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);})
.find(':checkbox').trigger('change');
```

I have other javascript scripts running in my block add_to_header - and all these scripts work like I expect them to, for the most they are encapulated in script tags with a function name eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAll(bx) {
  var cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i=0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    if(cbs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
      cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
    }
   }
}
</script>
```

And activated by 'onClick' events and other events. I have jquery in my base template - and as far as I can tell there should be no problem running this code. I tried embedding the code in script tags to get it to execute when the page loads - but nothing seems to work eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {
   $('table').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
   })
 .find(':checkbox').trigger('change');
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function()
{ 
$('table').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
   })
 .find(':checkbox').trigger('change');
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error in browser console ?

Comment: Not for this particular script - but it has an error for another script that is not being used, but loads with the page.

Comment: I'm a little confused -- your JSFiddle seems to be doing what you want. What's different? You may want to inspect source, and see if things have the classes you expect.